# how can sum of values matched with same column_name of two tables?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables like:

table_a

| id | cf_a | cf_b | cf_c | pv_a |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 6 |

table_b

| col | sum_cf | sum_pv |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | cf_a, cf_b, cf_c | pv_a |

then

I want to calculate by matching columns of table_a to 'sum_cf' and 'sum_pv' of table_b.

Expected output:

| id | sum_cf | sum_pv |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 3 |
| 2 | 7 | 4 |
| 3 | 10 | 5 |
| 4 | 13 | 6 |

Comment: Please share some of your code or what you've attempted to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can `CROSS JOIN` the tables and use a `CASE` expression and sub-string matches (including the surrounding delimiters to ensure you match a complete term) to determine whether to include a column in the sum:

```sql
SELECT b.col,
       a.id,
       CASE WHEN ', ' || b.sum_cf || ', ' LIKE '%, cf_a, %' THEN a.cf_a ELSE 0 END
       + CASE WHEN ', ' || b.sum_cf || ', ' LIKE '%, cf_b, %' THEN a.cf_b ELSE 0 END
       + CASE WHEN ', ' || b.sum_cf || ', ' LIKE '%, cf_c, %' THEN a.cf_c ELSE 0 END
       AS sum_cf,
       CASE WHEN ', ' || b.sum_pv || ', ' LIKE '%, pv_a, %' THEN a.pv_a ELSE 0 END
       AS sum_pv
FROM   table_a a
       CROSS JOIN table_b b
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_a (id, cf_a, cf_b, cf_c, pv_a) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 1, 2, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 2, 3, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3, 3, 4, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 4, 4, 5, 6 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table_b (col, sum_cf, sum_pv) AS
SELECT 'a', 'cf_a, cf_b, cf_c', 'pv_a' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| COL | ID | SUM_CF | SUM_PV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 4 | 3 |
| a | 2 | 7 | 4 |
| a | 3 | 10 | 5 |
| a | 4 | 13 | 6 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/r8Es-KjH)